Do there exist algorithms for nonlinear simply-connected Programming?
Suppose you are given a polyhedron of the form $A^Tx \le b$. Now your given a particular constraint on this polyhedron of the form $c_0 x_0^m + c_1 x_1 ... + c_n x_n \le b$.  Where $m$ initially is equal to 1 and $c_0 > 0$ .
The question is how MUCH can we decrease $m$ (lets say after decreasing we arrive at a constant $M$) while still insisting that the remaining shape remains simply connected $\forall m \ge M$ ?
I'm curious on both

Expressions that give bounds on $M$ even if intractable to compute
Efficient algorithms that allow us to actually get some pragmatic approximations of $M$

The motivation is that solving this kind of problem efficiently allows one to make progress towards more efficient schemes for $0-1$ integer programming by setting up a theory of non linear + non convex cuts.

Consider the family of feasible sets:
$$
\Omega(m) = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1} \mid A^T x \le b, c_0 x_0^m + \sum_{i=1}^n c_i x_i \le b \}.
$$
We seek the largest $M$ such that $\Omega(m)$ is simply connected for all $m \ge M$. For $m=1$, the set is defined by:
$$
A^T x \le b, \quad c_0 x_0 + \sum_{i=1}^n c_i x_i \le b.
$$
Define a continuous path of shapes:
$$
\Omega(t) = \Omega\bigl((1-t) + tm\bigr),\quad 0 \le t \le 1,
$$
with $t=0$ corresponding to $m=1$ and $t=1$ to a candidate exponent $m$. Maintaining connectivity of $\Omega(m)$ for $m \ge M$ is equivalent to preventing “topological fractures” as $t$ varies from 0 to 1.
Connectivity loss can occur when the nonlinearity $x_0^m$ induces disjoint regions. If $x_0>0$, decreasing $m$ below 1 increases $x_0^m$. When $x_0$ is large, $c_0 x_0^m$ may dominate $\sum_{i=1}^n c_i x_i$, creating disconnected feasible regions.
To establish bounds on $M$, let $\mathcal{C}(m)$ be the connected components of $\Omega(m)$, and define $\Phi(m) = |\mathcal{C}(m)|$. Let
$$
M^* = \inf \{ \alpha \ge 0 : \Phi(m)=1 \text{ for all } m \ge \alpha \}.
$$
Lower bounds on $M^*$ follow from showing that for $m$ in a certain range, all continuous paths in $\Omega(m)$ can be deformed within $\Omega(m)$ into each other. A “homotopy barrier” argument can be used: if a continuous path from $m=1$ to $m=\alpha$ avoids a topological phase transition (where $\Phi(m)>1$), then $\alpha \le M^*$.
For an upper bound on $M^*$, compare $\Omega(1)$ to its “pseudo-radial expansions.” Consider
$$
\Omega(1) = \{ x : A^T x \le b, c_0 x_0 + \sum_{i=1}^n c_i x_n \le b \}.
$$
Define
$$
F_m(x) = c_0 x_0^m + \sum_{i=1}^n c_i x_i.
$$
Comparing $F_1(x)$ with $F_m(x)$ for $x\in \Omega(1)$, note that when $x_0 \gg 1$, $x_0^m$ varies significantly with $m$. A sufficient condition for $\Omega(m) \subseteq \Omega(1)$ is
$$
x_0^m \le K x_0 + C \quad\text{for all } x\in \Omega(1),
$$
for some universal $K, C$. The smallest $m$ violating this in some region of $\Omega(1)$ bounds $M^*$ from above.
A homotopy-based approach uses an integral geometric viewpoint. Let
$$
H(x,t) = (1-t)\bigl(c_0 x_0 + \sum_{i=1}^n c_i x_i\bigr) + t\bigl(c_0 x_0^m + \sum_{i=1}^n c_i x_i\bigr).
$$
Then
$$
\Omega(t) = \{ x : A^T x \le b, H(x,t)\le b \}.
$$
Topologically, a transition from one to multiple connected components occurs when the critical points of $H(\cdot,t)$ cross the boundary $H(x,t)=b$. These critical points are found by analyzing
$$
\nabla_x H(x,t) = (1-t)\nabla_x\bigl(c_0 x_0 + \sum_{i=1}^n c_i x_n\bigr) + t\nabla_x\bigl(c_0 x_0^m + \sum_{i=1}^n c_i x_n\bigr).
$$
A new component's appearance can be linked to the alignment of $\nabla_x H(x,t)$ with the inequalities $A^T x \le b$. This alignment problem can help identify a “critical exponent” for connectivity, providing a theoretical basis for bounding $M^*$.
An approximation algorithm involves a bisection-style search over exponents. Starting with a range $[m_{\min},1]$, we pick a midpoint $m_{\text{mid}}$ and check if $\Omega(m_{\text{mid}})$ is connected. Connectivity can be checked by sampling points in $\Omega(m_{\text{mid}})$, building a graph where vertices are points and edges indicate points in the same neighborhood, and checking the graph's connectivity. If $\Omega(m_{\text{mid}})$ is connected, we lower the exponent; otherwise, we raise it. This iteratively narrows down the critical exponent:
def approximate_M_star(A, b, c, initial_range):
    left, right = initial_range  # e.g. (0, 1)
    while right - left > tolerance:
        mid = 0.5*(left + right)
        if is_connected(A, b, c, mid):
            left = mid
        else:
            right = mid
    return left

Here, is_connected(A, b, c, mid) constructs or samples $\Omega(\text{mid})$ and tests its connectivity (e.g., via union-find or a graph-based method).
The shape-changing exponent $m$ is tracked continuously, looking for “topological tipping points.”
